# When do Legolas and Gimli begin to respect and trust one another?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

During the time of the Fellowship, Elves and Dwarves weren't exactly the best of friends and this has been depicted by Legolas and Gimli. However, they eventually develop an incredibly strong friendship.

**When was the first moment in which these two characters began to respect and trust each other?**

---

*I am looking for sources from the novels.*

Comment: They made the films into novels?

Comment: I don't know, but I feel it must have involved interpretive dance.

Comment: They went for a cross-country stroll, played hide and seek in the Forest of Fangorn, went mountain climbing and hiking, equestrian, archery practice and other fun activities such as killing cave trolls and orcs. Why *wouldn't* they be friends?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### During their stay in Lothlórien

Although we're not given a great amount of insight into Legolas and Gimli's burgeoning friendship, this is clearly the time it begins (emphasis mine):

> Legolas was away much among the Galadhrim, and after the first night he did not sleep with the other companions, though he returned to eat and talk with them. Often he took Gimli with him when he went abroad in the land, and the others wondered at this change.
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 7: "The Mirror of Galadriel"</sup>
>
> The Company was arranged in this way: Aragorn, Frodo, and Sam were in one boat; Boromir, Merry, and Pippin in another; and **in the third were Legolas and Gimli, who had now become fast friends.**
>
> <sup>*Fellowship of the Ring* Book II Chapter 8: "Farewell to Lórien"</sup>

Comment: The answer isn't *They were snuggle buddies*?

Comment: As Jason Baker says there isn't much detail given here, but there are a couple of incidents we could point at which maybe broke the ice a bit: the shared experience of being (unfairly) blindfolded to enter Lothlorien, and the warm & respectful greeting for Gimli from Galadriel.

Comment: Maybe both of their mothers name were Martha?

Comment: Jason Baker nailed it. I would add that it probably started with Gimli being amazed by Galadriel's grace & kindness, and wanting to learn more about her & her realm. Of course, his best resource would be Legolas.

Comment: @AAT, only Gimli was "unfairly" blindfolded, however to stop any argument Aragorn suggested all the Fellowship be blindfolded (including Legolas) to settle Gimli and make it more fair.

Comment: @Edlothiad - all **equally** treated isn't necessarily all **fairly** treated. Legolas certainly wasn't happy about it, and so they had a shared experience here to draw on - that is the point I was making.  (In fact if an elven lawyer was in the building he might point out that Gimli **was** fairly blindfolded, since the law required it... but that's getting into a whole 'nother thing.)

Comment: @AAT Ah yes, I should've said equal.    I never said Gimli was unfairly blindfolded, my use of the word was to quote you. Either way, I still slightly disagree that Legolas being unhappy about being blindfolded would me him and Gimli would share the experience as in my opinion, they were unhappy for two separate reasons. (And Legolas' misfortune being cause by Aragorn wanting to treat Gimli as an equal)